# Recover flash drive - recognized by lsusb but not fdisk -l

Tags: usb, flash, data-recovery

I need to recover data off a seemingly broken flash drive.
physically no damage is noticeable.

the device is listed by lsusb

- Bus 002 Device 005: ID 090c:3000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)

i have tried to detect further with no progress using gparted testdisk and by looking in /dev for the device.

i think the device itself may need to be repaired somehow to pull the data off, any advice towards any solution would be very helpful.

edit: my bios recognizes it as well.